# Consume both "left" and "right" of Vavr Either?

Tags: java, vavr

How can I consume both a "left" or a "right" of a [vavr](https://www.vavr.io/) [Either](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.vavr/vavr/latest/io/vavr/control/Either.html) in a functional way?

I have a method that returns an `Either<RuntimeException, String>`. Based on this result, I need to execute a callback to our reporting library, e.g. `reportSuccess()` or `reportFailure()`. Consequently, I am looking for a nice, functional way of doing it. If an `Either` had a `biConsumer(Consumer<? super L> leftConsumer, Consumer<? super R> rightConsumer`, I could write something like:

```
Either<RuntimeException, String> result = // get the result from somewhere

result.biConsumer(ex -> {
  reportFailure();
}, str -> {
  repportSuccess();
});
```

The closest workaround I have found so far is the [biMap()](https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.vavr/vavr/1.0.0-alpha-3/io/vavr/control/Either.html#bimap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)) method, which would look something like

```
Either<RuntimeException, String> mappedResult = result.bimap(ex -> {
  reportFailure();
  return ex;
}, str -> {
  reportSuccess();
  return str;
});
```

Arguably, mapping functions should be used for mapping and not side effects, so even if it works I am looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's `peek` and `peekLeft` that – in combination – are pretty close to what you are looking for.

```
void reportFailure(RuntimeException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
void reportSuccess(String value) {
    System.out.println(value);
}

....

// prints: some value
Either<RuntimeException, String> right = Either.right("some value");
right.peekLeft(this::reportFailure).peek(this::reportSuccess);

// prints: java.lang.RuntimeException: some error
Either<RuntimeException, String> left = Either.left(
    new RuntimeException("some error")
);
left.peekLeft(this::reportFailure).peek(this::reportSuccess);
```